# Return records for last 6 months if no date supplied or last 6 months from date supplied

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that if no date is supplied it returns all records for the last 6 months, but what I want it to also do is return the records for the last 6 months from a date if one is supplied.

Using the code example below if no date was supplied then I would want to see records for February through to July. But if a date was supplied as in the code below I want to be able to see records for August through to July

```
DECLARE @IncidentDate DATE = null
DECLARE @EmpCode INT = 6000
SET @IncidentDate = '2018-02-05'

SELECT EmpCode
    ,BonusDate
    ,BonusYear
    ,BonusPeriod
    ,GradesScore
    ,Bonus
FROM Bonus  B
WHERE B.EmpCode = @EmpCode
    AND BonusDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Comment: [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

Comment: Larnu I know about ISNULL but how would I use it for what I require?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for some really good specific advice on posting question, and welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic here would seem to be that you want to take the last 6 months of records from either the incident date, if not null, or from now, if the incident date be null.  So, I think we can just coalesce the input date to now to get the behavior you want:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Bonus B
WHERE B.EmpCode = @EmpCode AND
    BonusDate >= DATEADD(month, -6, COALESCE(@IncidentDate, GETDATE()));
```

If you want the cutoff to be literally midnight of today, then use `CONVERT(date, GETDATE())` instead of just `GETDATE()`.

Edit: If you only want a six month window, then use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE B.EmpCode = @EmpCode AND
    BonusDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, COALESCE(@IncidentDate, GETDATE())) AND
                      COALESCE(@IncidentDate, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Tim tried your code but instead of returning 6 records it is bringing back all records

Comment: @DavidCleeton You didn't show any sample data, so obviously telling me there are 6 records is meaningless, and I can't pivot my answer based on that.

Comment: sorry that should have read its returning dates outside of the parameters required. When I entered a date for Feb 2017 it returned records from August 2016 to March 2018

Comment: So you only want a 6 month window from the incident date (or now minus 6 months, if the incident date be null)?  Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Check my updated answer.  Word to the wise: Next time include sample data so that we may see these edge cases.

Comment: Thank you Tim that worked perfectly. Appreciate your time and quick response